# Syncing Dropbox shared stuff

Tags: sync, dropbox

A friend of mine has shared his Dropbox folder with me which is nearly 1GB in size. When I click on saving it to my Dropbox, it says it will do the same and also download the stuff to my computer which has the Dropbox account synced.

I want to only add all this stuff to my Dropbox and not download the stuff to my computer.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on windows , right click the dropbox icon and click the small cog(gear) icon in the top right corner then  and go to `preferences`  in the context menu that pops up.
Go to `Advanced` tab where you will find `Selective Sync`
Select the folders you want the dropbox to download and sync for you.
Follow the [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D2xz.jpg) below:

[image]

[image]

[image]